# Solving $\sin^2(x)>2\sin^2(x/2)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have a following problem:

Show that $$\sin^2(x)>2\sin^2(x/2)$$  when  $0<x<\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2<x<2\pi$.

Can I show it by just checking inequality for each point but how to really show it mathematically?

Answer (score 2):

Use the double angle identity for $\sin$:

$$\sin(x) = 2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$$

Then your inequality is equivalent to $$4\sin^2(x/2)\cos^2(x/2) > 2 \sin^2(x/2)$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the [half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) 
$$2\sin^2(x/2)=1-\cos(x).$$
Then your inequality becomes
$$1-\cos^2(x)=\sin^2(x)>1-\cos(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin^2(x)>2\sin^2(x/2)$$
Use identities: 
$$
\sin^2(x/2)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2},\quad \sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)
$$
Then, we have 
$$
1-\cos^2(x)>1-\cos(x)\\
\cos(x)>\cos^2(x)
$$
For $0<x<\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2<x<2\pi$: $1>\cos(x)>0$, hence we can divide both sides by $\cos(x)$ and get:
$$
1>\cos(x)
$$
which, as already known, holds.